# ImageView elevation: shadow is cropped at the bottom

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-elevation

I want to add shadow around `ImageView`

I tried `elevation`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_compass"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

Layout Preview works fine

[image]

But on the device it looks like this

[image]

(shadow is cropped at the bottom)

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like parent view is clipping the shadow. Look for the parent that is clipping the shadow it might not be the immidiate parent. Add this to the parent view/s in the xml and check.

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

Comment: it didn't change anything

Comment: I also tried to add `android:clipToPadding="false"` to parent of this ImageView but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

instead of deciding the height and width in the xml , try to mention in the drawable and instead of using

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_compass"
```

use

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_icon_compass"
```